# Loading page as frame content in WPF, but dynamic resources in loaded page won't update dynamically?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

So, I've gone and did what Edd asked and rewrote this. The problem is a textblock with a dynamic resource as its content, updates properly when the textblock is on the mainwindow. But when I try to load page1 into a frame on the mainwindow, it loads but does not update the dynamic resource. I'm a total noob so not sure what I'm even looking for to find what's causing the issue, let alone fix it. Any help appreciated!

This is the application.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="TestString">This string is for testing.</sys:String>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This is the MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,299,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{DynamicResource TestString}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="110" Width="515" FontSize="48"/>

        <Button Content="Call Page" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,270,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Change Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="490,270,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the Page1.xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Page1">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{DynamicResource TestString}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="110" Width="515" FontSize="48"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And this is the MainWindow.xaml.vb (Code-Behind):

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        MainFrame.Content = New Page1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Resources("TestString") = "Test Completed."
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run the program and press both buttons, this is the result:

[Image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82ZmI.png)

The string updates for the Textblock on the MainWindow, but not for the one on Page1 called into the frame.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which illustrates the problem you're having. Include XAML. These tiny single-line snippets of code cannot be used to diagnose the problem, because nobody can guess when, or even if, they're being called, or what else is happening in the application.

Comment: Ok, thanks Ed, I've done what you said and rewrote my post. (Or should I repost it? Sorry, not sure what the etiquette here is!)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough update. Updating the original question is preferred. Every window and every control in WPF has its own Resources. When you do `Resources("TestString") = "Test Completed."` in MainWindow, you're creating a resource by that name in MainWindow's resource dictionary, not the App resource dictionary where the other pages get that resource from. Hence, I think you should try `App.Current.Resources("TestSTring") = "foo"` instead. Let me know if that works in VB.

Comment: Ahhh, THANKS!!! I wasted so many hours on this yesterday evening, and it was so simple. >_<

Yes, with using `Application.Current.Resources("TestString") = "foo"` it now works properly. Thanks!